# Setting up datawrapper on local server - understanding domains

Tags: dns, lamp, vps

It's been a long while since I setup my own LAMP server before the days of VPS. I decided to cancel my basic webhosting and go the route of a cheap VPS with Ubuntu where I can setup my own LAMP server.

My whole goal for this is to run and setup pageflow.io and datawrapper. Following the guide here https://github.com/datawrapper/datawrapper/wiki/Installing-Datawrapper I see it says

> Note that Datawrapper is designed to run on its own domain, so running
>   it inside a sub-directory (e.g. http://localhost/datawrapper) won't
>   work.

I get the process for this editing a virtual host in apache config but what does " run on its own domain" exactly mean? Is this going to conflict with anything else I install by point it to /www?

Thanks for any help, I am kind of confused with some of the new terminology i have not yet been exposed to. Any good reading material/explanations is appreciated!

thanks